# Saving python exception to reraise later while keeping traceback

Tags: python, exception, pickle, traceback

I'm currently writing decorators to cache results on disk. I would like that f(x) gives the same result whether f(x) has already been stored or not, **even when** f(x) raises an exception. i.e loading the stored result of f(x) when f has raised an exception should raise the same exception (with a slight modification indicating context).

I have successfully written the code for when f is stored is memory, but it does not work when using pickle (which would be used for saving on disk). Here is a full demo code. Note how it does not output the traceback when the exception has gone through pickle.

```py
import pickle, traceback, sys
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

def buggy(x):
    raise ValueError("my error")

def f(x):
    if x < 10:
        return buggy(x)
    else:
        return x+2



class DelayedException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, s):
        super().__init__(s)


for val, method in [
    (0, "no_cache"), (100, "no_cache"), #direct function call (what we want to imitate)
    (0, "memory_cached"), (100, "memory_cached"), #reraising later without saving/loading (currently good result)
    (0, "pickled_cache"), (100, "pickled_cache") #reraising later with saving/loading in between
]:
    print("\n\n")
    try:
        logger.info(f"val = {val}, method={method}")
        if method=="no_cache":
            res = f(val)
        else:
            try:
                res = f(val)
            except BaseException as e:
                # The code can be changed here
                try:
                    #Not very readable technique to append this exception in the exception stack.
                    #I'm very open to samething better
                    raise DelayedException(f"Error in {f.__name__}({val})") 
                except DelayedException as d:
                    try:
                        raise e from d
                    except BaseException as final:
                        res = final

            if method=="pickled_cache":
                #for simplicity we use a string instead of a file for demo purposes
                res = pickle.dumps(res) 
                res = pickle.loads(res)

            if isinstance(res, BaseException):
                # The code also can be changed here
                raise res

        logger.info(f"ok, res = {res}")
    except:
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
```

Any ideas on how to make it work? Comments in the code should give an idea on where I would like to change stuff.
Also, I have already looked into [tblib](https://pypi.org/project/tblib/), and it is unclear to me how I could use it for my purposes. Perhaps somebody sees how to adapt some of its inner workings to my problem?